# Flutter TextFormFeild issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using textFormFeild in flutter for data displaying. the text in each is initially set using bloc. when the page is opens, the page  automatically move towards the bottom where the textfield is present.

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
autofocus: false,
```

to your TextFormField widget